# Is it possible for anonymous user to upload on S3 storage to object which has public-read-write ACL without presigned URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph

I am setting object with public-read-write ACL with following code in python:

```py
o = s3.Object(bucket, key)
o.Acl().put(ACL='public-read-write')
```

I can now access object on `https://hostname/tenant:bucket/key` publicly.

Is it possible for anonymous user to upload something to this object?

Comment: Why do you want to allow public write to a bucket? That can be a real security issue, financially devastating, and problems with law enforcement. Hackers love public buckets that you pay for.

Comment: It is object, not bucket, but nevertheless you can impose limits to that in different manners. There are number of cases where you would like to that e.g. sharing spreadsheet or document, where "everyone with the link" have an access to that.

Comment: You do not want to make an object public write either. Similar risks for objects as well as buckets. You mention `impose limits`. What limits do you think you can impose on a public write object? If I can write to your object, I can put any type of data in that object.

Comment: You can have some proxy or gateway in front of it which does "something" before it gets to S3. Why would then Amazon then put this in documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/acl-overview.html#canned-acl Right question would be, why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check other S3 settings. For example, you need to disable "S3 Block Public Access", since Block Public Access will take precedence.
Also, you need to check bucket policy to allow access.
Please note, it's a good idea to use pre-signed url.

Comment: I am using CEPH, which has S3 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting policy for specific object with something like:

```py
import boto3, json

public_read_write_policy = {
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Action": [
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   },
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
   ],
   "Sid": ""
  },
  {
   "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
   ],
   "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
     "s3:prefix": [
      "OBJECT_NAME",
     ]
    }
   },
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   },
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
   ],
   "Sid": ""
  },
  {
   "Action": [
    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
    "s3:PutObject"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   },
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME",
   ],
   "Sid": ""
  }
 ],
 "Version": "2012-10-17"
}


try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',
        aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY',
        aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY',
        endpoint_url="S3_ENDPOINT",
        use_ssl=False,
        verify=False,
    )

    policy = {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": public_read_write_policy
    }

    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket='BUCKET_NAME', Policy=json.dumps(policy))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```